# Pegar dados utilizando join em duas tabela 1 para muitos

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, join

bom dia,

Preciso realizar um select de duas tabelas que estão relacionadas 1 para muitos:

Tabela 1: produtos
Tabela 2: grupo de preços

Preciso pegar todos os preços da tabela grupo de preços, que pode ter 1 ou mais.

No meu caso do select abaixo ele até pega os preços mais repete todos os dados como se fosse outro produto, como posso fazer para que cada produtos vem já com todos os preços correspondente a ele?

Estou utilizando Codeigniter, abaixo o select que estou utilizando atualmente.

```
$this->db->select('produtos.*, grupo_preco_produtos.grupo_preco_venda');
$this->db->from('produtos');
$this->db->join('grupo_preco_produtos', 'grupo_preco_produtos.id_produto = produtos.id');
$this->db->where(array('produtos.id_empresa' =>$id_empresa, 'produtos.del' => 0, 'produtos.tipo_produto' => 1,));
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: Já pensou como utilizaria isso depois? As vezes o que vc deseja fazer não é a melhor opção e o pessoal aqui poderia te ajudar com uma melhor solução.

Comment: Você quer trazer eles separados por vírgula?

Comment: Então Denis eu preciso montar uma lista com o produtos e seus preços, não queria ter que para cada linha ter que conectar no banco pra pegar os dados, acho que isso pode sobrecarregar o banco de dados, por se tratar de um erp que vai ter vários clientes ou vc acha que não sobrecarrega o banco

Comment: Sorack, pode ser sim e de pois na hora de listar posso separar.

Comment: Sim Denis, sei disso pode ser que o que estou fazendo pode não ser a melhor opção, caso os amigos tiver outra opção melhor por favor pode me passar sem nenhum problema

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso você utiliza o [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Sua Query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT produtos.*, GROUP_CONCAT(grupo_preco_produtos.grupo_preco_venda SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM produtos
INNER JOIN grupo_preco_produtos ON grupo_preco_produtos.id_produto = produtos.id
WHERE produtos.id_empresa = '.$id_empresa.' AND produtos.del = 0 AND produtos.tipo_produto = 1
GROUP BY produtos.id;
```

Outra dica que eu dou é você apelidar suas tabelas quando utilizar join's, essa mesma query ficaria desta forma:

```
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.grupo_preco_venda SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM produtos a
INNER JOIN grupo_preco_produtos b ON b.id_produto = a.id
WHERE a.id_empresa = '.$id_empresa.' AND a.del = 0 AND a.tipo_produto = 1
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar um `GROUP_CONCAT` à sua query:

```
$this->db->select('produtos.*, GROUP_CONCAT(grupo_preco_produtos.grupo_preco_venda SEPARATOR ",") as grupo_preco_venda');
$this->db->group_by('produtos.id');
```

Comment: Dessa forma não deu, dessa forma ele concatenou todos os preços e listou somente um produto. e na verdade tem listar todos os produtos com os preços referente a ele.

Comment: @ClaytonEduardoMergulhão fiz uma alteração, dá uma olhada ai